# OpenSocial server implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-networking, opensocial, apache-shindig

What is the preferred method of implementing the OpenSocial platform? I'm aware of Apache Shindig but can't really find any useful information on it. Also, is it possible to use an existing solution like the Rails-based [lovdbyless](http://lovdbyless.com/) and add OpenSocial features to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a plugin that someone started, Ruby on Rails, [OpenSocial Container plugin 0.1.0](http://rails.elctech.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-opensocial-container-plugin-0-0-2), the comments have someone from Apache Shindig suggesting it get rolled into there as the Ruby server implementation.

I also found an article on rolling your own, [Google's OpenSocial with Ruby on Rails](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2007/11/7/opensocial-with-ruby-on-rails).

I haven't tried, either, yet.

Answer (score 2):

I've ported shindig over to .NET at http://code.google.com/p/pesta/ and a sample site using it from partuza at http://www.codeplex.com/raya

Answer (score 1):

Even some of the guys on the Shindig team admit that the documentation is very sparse, to the extent that they say the source code *is* the documentation - and, believe me, there's quite a bit of source code to look at.

The most helpful links I've found are these:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-shindig-dev/200805.mbox/raw/%3CF60DD781-F361-4865-AEC6-284644D0DFF3@xs4all.nl%3E/

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SHINDIG/The+rough+guide+to+deploying+shindig

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-shindig-dev/200905.mbox/%3c4CC1540B3EC8D54AA01CC6BC40F71030E0991E@EXCHANGE.corp.shop.com%3e

and for an example of how to replace the default classes so as to interact with a database:

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SHINDIG/Providing+your+own+data+service+implementation